# Appium iOS kill app without the plist being removed

Tags: ios, ruby, appium

I am trying to run the following steps:
1. Launch app the first time, see terms and agreement
2. Agree to terms and agreement
3. Kill app and relaunch
4. You should not see terms and agreement

Right now, appium is running on without the --no-reset flag, since I do need the app to be reset between scenarios, but the following re-launched the app with the plist deleted (it's like remove the app and relaunch again)

```
sleep(3)
pf_name = $driver.caps['platformName']
pf_ver = $driver.caps['platformVersion']
dev_name = $driver.caps['deviceName']
auto_accept_alert = $driver.caps['autoAcceptAlerts']
app_path = $driver.caps['app']
Appium::Driver.new({ caps: { platformName: pf_name, platformVersion: pf_ver, deviceName: dev_name, autoAcceptAlerts: auto_accept_alert, app: app_path, noReset: true} })
$driver.restart
$driver.close_app
$driver.launch_app
```

I also tried $driver.close_app and $driver.launch_app, but they did the same thing (remove the plist as well as killing the app).

Is there any way I can just kill the app without removing plist?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

It's somewhat of an all-around involved sort of answer.

1. Tag the scenario that needs killing and relaunching without resetting with something, say @needPlist
2. In the hooks.rb, in the Before for @needPlist, call the Appium::Driver.new with the noReset flag set to true. Call a $driver.restart (Make sure that in the After for the same tag, you call the Appium::Driver.new with the noReset flag set to false, and restart the driver again)
3. In the step definition, you can now call $driver.close_app and $driver.launch_app without losing your plist

That should do the trick, I think.